# Como adicionar e remover classe de acordo com a viewport

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de adicionar uma classe quando a `viewport` for menor que `899px` 
e remover quando a `viewport` for maior que isso.

A principio meu código funcionou, 
mas sem remover a classe quando a `viewport` aumenta.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth < 800) {
            document.querySelector('.layout-fixed-header').classList.add("layout-small-menu");
    }
});
```

Qual seria a melhor maneira de montar esse código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sempre que puderes faz cache dos elementos que vais buscar com `document.querySelector`, especialmente dentro de um `.resize()` isso pode pesar o browser.

A minha sugestão seria fazer isso com CSS somente... usando media queries:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  .layout-small-menu {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .layout-small-menu {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}
```

Mas para responder à tua pergunta podias fazer assim:

```js
var fixedHeader = document.querySelector('.layout-fixed-header');
$(window).resize(function() {
  var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
  fixedHeader.classList.toggle("layout-small-menu", viewportWidth < 800);
});
```

Neste caso usei o `.toggle()` que adiciona ou remove a classe consoante o valor do segundo argumento que lhe é passado.